# Redirect everything inside subdirectory but not subdirectory itself

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a multilingual wordpress site that went live and replaces the old site.

Not every language is translated yet, so I want to keep the old site alongside wordpress for the other languages.

- `example.de` -> new wordpress site
- `example.de/zh-hans/*` -> redirect to `example.de/cn/`
- `example.de/zh-hans/` -> redirect to `example.de/cn/`
- `example.de/en/*` -> redirect to `example.de/en/`
- `example.de/en/` -> just stay on `example.de/en/`

My .htaccess looks like this at the moment:

```
Redirect 302 /zh-hans/ /cn/
RedirectMatch 302 ^/(zh-hans)/. /cn/
Redirect 302 /ja/ /jp/
RedirectMatch 302 ^/(ja)/. /jp/
RedirectMatch 302 ^/(en)/. /en/

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

`en`, `jp` and `cn` are actual folders with index.html files in them. WordPress uses `en`, `ja` and `zh-hans` for these languages.

I have some problems with this:

1. Only `example.de/ja/` and `example.de/zh-hans/` are working as intended
2. `example.de/ja` (without ending slash) and all other language paths like that just redirect to `example.de/`
3. `example.de/en`, `example.de/en/` end up in a redirect loop
4. everything that comes after and ending slash (`example.de/ja/some-path`) is opened by wordpress with a 404-page

At this point I have no idea how to handle this and I've tried different combinations for hours.

Is there even a way to handle this via .htaccess?

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing your `Redirects` with `RewriteRules` :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^zh-hans/?$ /cn/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(zh-hans)/. /cn/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^ja/?$ /jp/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(ja)/. /jp/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^en$ /en/ [L,R]
```

I also made the trailing slash optional in some specific patterns . It should work now.